# Remover registros duplicados MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tenho uma coleção com o campo chamado "contact_id".
Na minha coleção eu tenho registros duplicados com essa chave.

Como posso remover duplicatas, resultando em apenas um registo?
Já tentei:

```
db.Person Duplicate.ensureIndex ({ "contact_id": 1}, {únicas: verdadeiro, dropDups: true})
```

Mas não funcionou, porque a função dropDups não está mais disponível no MongoDB 3.x

**Eu estou usando 3.2**

Answer (score 1):

Esse exemplo abaixo agrupará os documentos da coleção `clientes` pelos campos `nome` e `cidade`. Depois ela excluirá os duplicados. Pode fazer que não tem erro.

```
db.clientes.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"nome":"$nome","cidade":"$cidade"}, dups:{$push:"$_id"},count:{$sum: 1}}},
{$match:{count: {$gt: 1}}}
]).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.dups.shift();
    db.clientes.remove({_id : {$in: doc.dups}});
});
```

Fonte: http://codigosimples.net/2016/03/07/remover-registros-duplicados-com-mongodb/

Comment: Essa solução é perfeita, pois ela removerá os duplicados deixando sempre o registro original.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo você usar a função Upsert na hora de inserir os dados. Ele vai procurar no mongodb se os dados escolhidos já existem, se sim, o objeto existente será excluído e um novo será gerado, se não, um novo será criado. Os campos existentes no novo objeto deverão obrigatoriamente ser setados na função. (.Set("Variavel", dados.Variavel)). Deixo abaixo um exemplo

```
public void UpsertDados (Dados dados)
        {
            FilterDefinition<Dados> filter = Builders<Dados>.Filter.Where(c => c.Variavel == dados.Variavel);
            UpdateDefinition<Data> updateCommand = Builders<Dados>.Update
                      .Set("Variavel", dados.Variavel);

            getCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, updateCommand, defaultUpdateOptions);
        }
```